# opening PgAdmin 4 in Chrome

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I want to open PgAdmin 4 in Chrome. I have right clicked the icon in the Windows System Tray and selected Configure... In the Browser Command input, I have added the following:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --app=%URL%
```

The program keeps loading but won't come up. What should I do?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a strange behavior with the new version 4.28 that is addressed in the [FAQ](https://www.pgadmin.org/faq/#12):

> **When I launch pgAdmin 4 v4.28 or later on Windows, the loading page
> never closes. Why?**
>
> pgAdmin 4 v4.28 includes additional security features, one of which is
> intended to prevent security issues caused by Content Sniffing.
>
> Unfortunately some Windows systems are mis-configured such that this
> causes Javascripts used by pgAdmin to fail to load. Opening the
> developer tools on your browser will show an error similar to this:
>
> Refused to execute script from
> 'http://127.0.0.1:57313/static/vendor/require/require.min.js?ver=42800'
> because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict
> MIME type checking is enabled.
>
> (index):39 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at
> (index):39
>
> This will occur when the value of the registry key at
> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.js\Content Type is set to text/plain. **To resolve
> the issue, use the Registry Editor and reset the value of
> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.js\Content Type to:**
>
> **text/javascript**
>
> Finally, restart the pgAdmin server.

Answer (score 0):

Correct name of the key is `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.js\Content Type`.

Restarting the PostgreSQL server after this modification accomplished by me via Services.

In addition I had to stop the pgAdmin process in task manager before I was able to successfully load a new pgAdmin tab in the browser.